# Understanding $\mathscr{L}_Y^{\text{down} }=-\sqrt{2}\sum _{a,q}\overline{\psi }_{iL}Y^{\text{down} }_{iq}q'_RH+\text{h.c.} $

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, standard-model, higgs, electroweak

Currently reading Bilenky's "Introduction to the Physics of Massive and Mixed Neutrinos." (2nd ed.)

On page 56 (Section 3.4 on the Standard model) elaborates

> "Let us assume that in the total Lagrangian of the SM there is the following Lagrangian of the Yuwaka interaction of the quark and Higgs fields"
> $$\mathscr{L}_Y^{\text{down} }=-\sqrt{2}\sum _{a,q}\overline{\psi }_{iL}Y^{\text{down} }_{iq}q'_RH+\text{h.c.} \tag{Eq. 3.126}$$

Where

- $Y^{\text{down} }_{iq}$ is a complex $3\times 3$ matrix.
- $q(x)$ is the quark field.
- $\psi _{iL}$ and $H $ are $SU(2)$ doublets.
- $q'_R$ are singlets.

I can't seem to understand the equation at all. And more importantly, I can't seem to see how is the product defined at all. If $Y$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix, how do we do the product with doublets?

Also, why is the sum over $a$ and $q$? I would expect $q$ to be there but what's $a$ all about? Maybe a typo?

I'm also unsure as to what $\psi $ means here. My best guess is that it's the doublets presented at the beginning of the section (3.4):
[image]

Comment: $a$ seems to be a typo indeed, I think it should be replaced by $i$. Thus, $Y^\text{down}_{iq}$ is not a matrix, but the components of a $3\times 3$ matrix.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I really wish this great book had an errata online...